# MS Office Update removes my ODBC Connection to MySQL Server

Tags: microsoft-access, odbc

I've had couple times where an Office Update cleared or removed MS Access Database ODBC connection to MySQL server. I have three people using this database, and if anyone updates their Office Suite the link will be removed from their Access Front End.

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening, besides not allowing updates?

Comment: Use a DSN-less connction?

Comment: I am not. I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Just search for "DSN-less connection".